# SIGBART Error while assigning a value to UITableView from SQLITE

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, sigabrt

I am new to the database development on Xcode using SQLite and trying to build an app which gets data from table and puts it into the Tableview.

I have following code in the Tableview:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView : (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
jobs =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
id cellvalue;

NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select jobTitle FROM job"];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];


if (cell == nil)
{
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        //[jobs addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
        [jobs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
        cellvalue =[jobs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellvalue;
       // cell.textLabel.text = [jobs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; -- Tried this but does not work.

    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Here JobTitle is a text field in SQLITE DB. Table name is Job. I get SIGBART error on following steps:

```
cellvalue =[jobs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellvalue;
```

OR I have tried following

```
cell.textLabel.text = [jobs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

When I tried:

```
cell.textlabel.text = @"Test"
```

it does work fine.

I am stuck here and would appreciate help on how to assign a text value from database to TableView cells. Currently there are 2 rows in the table.

Comment: write code of data fetching in `viewDidLoad` and then use only that array in `cellForRow`

Comment: I will try it and let you know how it goes. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with the assigning value to table cells, but with the jobs array. Possibly it has less values than count of rows in the table. Check that at first.

Comment: You were correct. I was able to resolve this by making following change in the array addobject:         while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            
            [jobs addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

maybe, bacause your cellvalue has type id, and tried to set id to NSString in

cell.textLabel.text = cellvalue;

it will be better if you can provide error description

Comment: Error shows nothing more than following. I have tried to step through each step but no content is displayed on lldb : 0x2013a6a:  jae    0x2013a7a                 ; __pthread_kill + 26

Comment: Agree with you as well. I was able to resolve the issue by making following change:         while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            
            [jobs addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
            
        }